# Inequality with sum and harmonic mean

Tags: inequality, summation, means

I need some help with this please(difficult college homework)...

Prove that if $n \in \mathbb{N^*}$ and $t_1, t_2, ..., t_n \in \mathbb{ℝ^*_+}$ are such that
$(\sum\limits_{k=1}^nt_k^2)(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{t_k}) = 2(\sum\limits_{k=1}^nt_k)$ and$(\sum\limits_{k=1}^nt_k)(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{t_k}) = \frac{3}{2}n^2$ then $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{t_k^3}{\sum\limits_{j=1,j\ne k}^nt_j^2} \ge \frac{n}{2}H(t_1,t_2,...,t_n)$, where $H(t_1, t_2, ...t_n)$ is the harmonic mean of $t_1, t_2,...,t_n$

I have spent almost a day on this problem. I first expanded right side of the inequality using the harmonic mean formula and identities I have, reaching to smth like this: $\frac{1}{3}\sum\limits_{k=1}^nt_k$. Then I pretended $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{t_k^3}{\sum\limits_{j=1,j\ne k}^nt_j^2}$ can be rewritten as $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{t_k^3}{\sum\limits_{j=1}^nt_j^2-t_k^2}$
which I said it's $\ge$ than $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{t_k^3}{\sum\limits_{j=1}^nt_j^2}$.I feel i did it wrong here, however that was the best I could do. Then I separated this sum in two independent sums and tried to find some inequality related to the right side of the main inequality.
I tried with cube mean $\ge$ rms $\ge$ am but still nothing. I sense a modified version of Holder inequality or other super stuff like that might help, but I'm running out of energy so I would appreciate a little help

(Btw,I am new to TeX and math.stackexchange)
Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1500697/harmonic-mean-inequality ?

Comment: indeed, same problem as mine

Comment: Same comment as that one, the conditions seem to restrict $n \le 3$ which doesn't look right somehow.

Comment: well, I'm sure I didn't mispell anything

Comment: Well then all you have to check is for $n=1, 2, 3$, which ought to be simple.  $n=1$ doesn't give anything meaningful, but perhaps the others will lead to something sensible.

Comment: is it really that simple?LE:I'll give it a try(thanks)

Comment: As it is written, there is no way $n> 3$.  Doubt that's the intent, still think the question has some unintended error. Was the question from some reference text?

Comment: no, this problem is part of a larger pdf homework with no references, only tasks

Comment: this is the paper(3rd problem) [link](http://thor.info.uaic.ro/~fliacob/An1/2015-2016/Teme/Tema%201%20_%2026%20oct%202015/Tema%201E_subiecte_26%20oct%202015.pdf)

Comment: The problem is set wrong I guess.  Will answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the conditions and Holder's inequality: 
$$3n^2=\left(\sum t_k^2\right) \left(\sum \frac1{t_k}\right)^2 \ge n^3 \implies n \le 3$$

Now $n=1$ gives $t_1 \cdot \frac1{t_1} = \frac32$ which is not possible.

For $n=2$, the conditions can be written as for $x, y > 0$ 
$$(x^2+y^2)\left(\frac1x+\frac1y \right)=2(x+y), \quad (x+y)\left(\frac1x+\frac1y \right)=6$$
$$\implies 3(x^2+y^2) = (x+y)^2 \implies x^2+y^2=xy $$
which is not possible.

We are left with $n=3$, where we may write the condition for $x, y, z > 0$
$$(x^2+y^2+z^2)\left(\frac1x+\frac1y+\frac1z \right)=2(x+y+z), \quad (x+y+z)\left(\frac1x+\frac1y +\frac1z\right)=\frac{27}2$$
$$\implies 27(x^2+y^2+z^2)=4(x+y+z)^2$$
But from the well known inequality $3(x^2+y^2+z^2) \ge (x+y+z)^2$, the above is not possible.

Hence there is no $n$ for which the conditions are satisfied, hence trivially the result is true.

Comment: we have the AM-HM inequality $$ \frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^nt_k}{n} \ge \frac{n}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{t_k}}$$ which turns into$$ (\sum\limits_{k=1}^nt_k)(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{t_k}) \ge n^2$$ Now if we replace $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^nt_k$ by $ \frac{(\sum\limits_{k=1}^nt_k^2)(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{t_k})}{2} $ based on $(\sum\limits_{k=1}^nt_k^2)(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{t_k}) = 2(\sum\limits_{k=1}^nt_k)$ we get $$ 3n^2 =(\sum\limits_{k=1}^nt_k^2)(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{t_k})^2 \ge 2n^2 $$ so it should work for any n in $ \mathbb{N^*}$

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: $t_1 \cdot \frac1{t_1} = \frac32$ that is weird indeed

Comment: still there is no value for n such that starting with that value the identities in the hypothesis hold?

Comment: Have rechecked, you haven't used Holder. The correct RHS is **not** $2n^2$, it is $n^3$ using Holder.

Comment: but using AM-HM seems to give a tighter bound on RHS which should be more helpful considering I applied that right

Comment: or you mean my AM-HM method doesn't hold because the identities don't hold?

Comment: Clearly $n^3>2n^2$ for most $n$, so Holder gives a tighter bound in this case.

Comment: could you please show me step by step how you applied Holder?

Comment: There is only one step, perhaps you will recognise this version better: $$\left(\sum t_k^2\right)^{1/3}\cdot \left(\sum \frac1{t_k}\right)^{2/3}\ge \sum t_k^{2/3}\frac1{t_k^{2/3}}=n$$

Comment: Your answer solved my problem.Thanks!